# JQuery - Pass coordinates of element to ASP.NET code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a simple ASP.NET site which will use the `offset` or `position` functions provided by JQuery to pass the coordinates of a `<div>` element to an ASP.NET code behind via a button's `OnClick` method.

I've searched and found [this example](http://forums.asp.net/post/5005609.aspx) but it doesn't seem to work as expected, upon clicking no coordinates are returned.

How do I obtain the coordinates of a given `<div>` element and pass these to an ASP.NET button's `OnClick` method?

Comment: What didn't work? That page looks like it's setting values of hidden fields. Did you check the hidden fields in the code-behind?

Comment: Did you click the button first?

Comment: Have you debug the code behind? That example seems ok. and post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1**
To get location of the element you can use either [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XFfLP/

```
function test() {
    var p = $("#testID");
    var position = p.offset();//p.position()
    $("#Field1").val(position.top);
    $("#Field2").val(position.left);
}​
```

**PART 2**
To pass data from pages to server code-behind you can use `Web-Methods`

Article: http://blog.nitinsawant.com/2011/09/draft-sending-client-side-variables-to.html

**1.** Web-Method sample code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string AcceptData(object jsonData)
 {
     Customer newCust =(Customer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData.ToString(),typeof(Customer));
     return "Server response: Hello "+newCust.FirstName;
 }
```

**2.** JS sample Code:

```
var newCustomer = {
    "FirstName": $("#txtFirstName").val(),
    "LastName": $("#txtLastName").val(),
    "Telephone": $("#txtTelephone").val()
}

var jsonData = "{'jsonData':'" + JSON.stringify(newCustomer) + "'}";//create string representation of the js object

        //post data to server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Test.aspx/AcceptData',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                //call successfull
                var obj = msg.parseJSON();
                alert(obj.d); //d is data returned from web services

                //The result is wrapped inside .d object as its prevents direct execution of string as a script
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                //error occurred
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```